# containsObject: returning NO when isEqual and hash match

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSMutableOrderedSet that I'm adding and removing MTLModels from. The hash and isEqual methods will both return true for two objects, but containsObject will return false.

Sometimes this code works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
models count: 1
isEqual: 1
hashes equal: 1
containsObject: 0
```

How is it possible the below code could print out the above?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableOrderedSet *models;

- (void)remove:(MTLModel *)model {
  NSLog(@"models count: %d", self.models.count);
  MTLModel *modelInSet = (MTLModel *)self.models.firstObject;
  NSLog(@"isEqual: %d", [modelInSet isEqual:model]);
  NSLog(@"hashes equal: %d", modelInSet.hash == model.hash);
  NSLog(@"containsObject: %d", [self.models containsObject:model]);
}
```

**Update:**

As a follow-up, this returns YES when the NSMutableOrderedSet returns NO:

```
[[self.models array] containsObject:model]
```

**Update 2:**

If I check if modelInSet is contained in self.models, that also returns NO, even though it's the object returned by firstObject.

Comment: That looks strange indeed. Can you show your implementation of `isEqual:` and `hash`?

Comment: Yeah, you can see both here: https://github.com/github/Mantle/blob/master/Mantle/MTLModel.m#L217

Comment: What does `[self.models containsObject:modelInSet]` return? If it returns `NO`, then I suspect you are mutating your object after you added it to the set, which is not allowed. This explains why a new collection works properly.

Comment: It does indeed return NO and I am mutating the object. I add it to the set and it has properties that are updated after a request to the server finishes.

Comment: Yup, see answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably mutating the object after adding it to the set. This is not allowed. The set does not recalculate hashes, so if you mutate the object, it will have a different hash from the one stored by the set. This is why creating a new collection (array in your case) works, i.e. because it recalculates all the hashes.

EDIT: To be clear, you can mutate an object after adding it to the set, but its hash value must not change.

Comment: Thanks so much! I probably should have looked over the docs more carefully, but it never would have occurred to me before that this might be the case (I'm new to Objective-C).

Comment: In the case where the hash will change, is there any way to have the set clear its hash cache?

Comment: No problemo! Also, I might be mistaken but I don't think this is exclusive to Objective-C. :-)

Comment: Regarding forcing hash recalculation, I believe there is no way to do this with NSMutable(Ordered)Set. Well…I guess you can remove the object before mutating and add it again afterwards. =P

Comment: With Arrays I know this is not the case, is there a document that supports your assertion?

Comment: @GradyPlayer Which assertion? If you mean my answer, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash).

Comment: your assertion that you can not mutate object in a set.

Comment: @GradyPlayer, arrays do not uses hashes to organize their storage.